# Check whether a state variable includes a substring

Tags: reactjs, include, state

`this.state.foo.includes('bar') returns: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`

Just curious. I am to trying to check whether a substring in a state variable exists. Let's say my state looks like this:

```
this.state = {
    something: 'foo bar'
}
```

Now in the return() function I would like to check whether this.state.something contains the substring 'foo'.

I know I could do that using:
    this.state.something === 'foo bar' ? dothis : dothat

But since the state variables content is set by an external JSON file, I don't know the exact content of the string beforehand and also in this particular place in my code I am only interested whether 'foo' is present as a substring.

If I try:

```
this.state.something.includes('foo') ? dothis : dothat
```

I get a: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`

`indexOf()` and `match()` produce errors as well.

What can I do? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.state.something might not be defined at the time of use.
You could probably set its default value to an empty string in the constructor or check to see if this.state.something is defined first before using it

```
constructor() {
   this.state = {
     something: ''
   }
}
```

OR

```
this.state.something && this.state.something.includes('foo');
```

Comment: Thanks to all! this.state.something && this.state.something.includes('foo'); does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `includes`, it must be called on an instance of a string. So for example, if the value of `this.state.something` is `undefined`, you’ll get this error.

You could initialize the value as a string, or use a simple existence check first like `this.state.something && this.state.something.includes(‘foo’)`. In either case you’ll still get an error if the value is not a string, so you might consider a typecheck as well.